# Can't run android emulator

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I installed the mobile development option for Visual Studio 2017, and created a new mobile app (Xamarin.forms) in the blank app template.

I tried to run the app, but I got the message `The ADB binary found at is obsolete`.

I downloaded the update from the SDK manager, and the message was gone, but now when I try to run the app, the emulator shows a black screen for a few seconds, and then the status strip shows the message `Deploy canceled`, and the emulator closes.

How can I fix it?

Comment: look which [acceleration is available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54869470/1466046). Also run Xamarin device manager and play with GPU settings of the virtual device

Answer (score 0):

The error message is vague, you'll need to provide more information if you want someone to answer this.
To do so, you want to enable the diagnostics output in VS:

[image: xamarin diagnostics output verbosity]

Here is a couple of things you can do in the meantime:

- run VS as administrator
- clean your project
- go to the project folder and delete all the files under /bin and /obj
- rebuild the project

Then try to deploy your application

Comment: I did what you suggested, and add a comment contains an image of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

The running process failed now because of deployment errors (after I did what Guillermo Gerard suggested):

[image: The errors]

Comment: Those are not errors, and the project *should* be able to run with some warnings.
I've faced problems  in the past when there are pending updates (even skype updates!!). I see that you have a pending update there, could you go through that and try all the build process again? (the whole long process: clean, delete files, rebuild, run)

Comment: @GuillermoGerard It still writing `deploy failed`

Comment: Well, you can check if you have the JDK9 installed, this can be your problem (according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/jdk9-errors#known-issues-with-jdk-9)
Another thing to have in mind: Are you running VS as administrator? If not, do it and test again