# Android Emulator on AMD/Win 10

Tags: android-emulator, windows-10, amd-processor, hypervisor, bsod

I've read ton of links with the procedure to use hardware acceleration for Android emulator on Ryzen processor/Win 10. I've enabled Windows Hypervisor Platform and SVM on Bios (I'm on Ryzen 7 2700x/X-470-i), but all I get is a BSOD. I can enter the OS only if I switch off SVM. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try x86_64 image instead of x86 and [check if emulator uses acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54869470/1466046)

Comment: accel:
3
Android Emulator requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX support.  Your CPU: 'AuthenticAMD'

Comment: update the UEFI

Comment: can you find a new UEFI/BIOS update?