# Android Emulator in Visual Studio, taking too long to respond?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am working with visual studio 2019 for the projects in  C++,C#,.NET languages. But now I need to work on Xamarin also. My problem is while debugging the Xamarin in Android Emulator it takes too long and some times it takes 1 hour and Some times it will not show any output, and if output shown in the emulator, it  takes time to respond to user inputs .

Is any other option to test this Xamarin applications in low load ?
I have windows 10 installed laptop , it is 4GB RAM intel core i3 processor

Comment: Have you installed intel HAXM? That is normally recommended (I believe also part of the xamarin android instructions). Though I doubt it is the root cause of the issue, but your PC specs are very low

Comment: yes already installed

Comment: upgrade the RAM amount and [check if HW acceleration is used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54869470/1466046)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the option,

I can use my own android phone to debug with the visual studio, it is pretty easy and it will not take much time to debug.

How to do this available in following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development